# Get result from 2 columns with limit and desc

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM VB_Names
WHERE Buurt = 'Spangen'
    AND Gender  = 'M'
    AND Gender  = 'V'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 6
```

I would like to have 3 results from the column Gender 'M' and 3 results from the column Gender 'V' both with Count on DESC.

Comment: You have the AND condition between Gender  = 'M'
AND Gender  = 'V'. I assume this is not right as one column can not have two different values at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gender cannot be both 'M' and 'V' in the same row, so this query will return nothing.  Instead, use `union all`:

```
(SELECT *
 FROM VB_Names
 WHERE Buurt = 'Spangen' AND Gender = 'M'
 ORDER BY count DESC
 LIMIT 3
) UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM VB_Names
 WHERE Buurt = 'Spangen' AND Gender = 'V'
 ORDER BY count DESC
 LIMIT 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `AND` condition to `OR`

```
SELECT *
FROM VB_Names
WHERE Buurt = 'Spangen'
    AND (Gender  = 'M' OR Gender  = 'V')
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: `Gender  IN( 'M', 'V')` for brevity. But you can't guarantee that you'll get 3 of each that way.